# Starting with SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Have just downloaded SQLite amalgamation 3070900 as I wish to develop some experience in SQLite databases.

I have managed to get it out of the box. Where to now! How do I get the engine to start! How best should I commence so as to get some practice things going with the SQLite package?  Cannot find much basic stuff on the web.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What platform are you using?  Need more information for us to have a hope of helping...

Comment: http://sqlite.org has a wealth of information

Comment: Using Windows 7. Just trying to get to know the Sqlite thing or put it another way - taking the tour. Not finding it straightforward!

Answer (score 4):

SQLite is an embedded database, it has no "engine" *per se*.  It's implemented as a single loadable library (a DLL on windows).  You do not need the C source code, which is what you appear to have downloaded, to use it.

SQLite itself has no user interface nor any way for you to interact with it directly.  There is a very simple command-line interface program available for most (all?) platforms, however, called sqlite3 (sqlite3.exe on Windows).  With that program you can create and work with databases.  You might find it easier, however, to use one of the many GUI SQLite manager programs available on the web.

To *program* against the SQLite database you will need to choose a programming language and make sure you have the correct SQLite interface libraries.

Comment: There's a guide to using the command-line interface at http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html

Comment: Have looked into http://www.sqlite.org/download.html again. Cant seem to make sense of all the info on that page! Where do I find the sqlite3.exe download for windows?

Comment: On this page: http://www.sqlite.org/download.html download the command-line shell in the Windows section.

Comment: The runtime is bundled with Python. Great way to start!

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of video tutorials for SQLite on YouTube... I particularly recommend [the ones by Jay Godse](http://www.youtube.com/user/Jaynonymous1#p/c/463DF6FFEF8D05FA/9/NYlCVoj4peg), aka 'jaynonymous1'.  The very first one is a little rough; later epsiodes explore specific features like autoincrement, unions, joins, foreign keys, check constraints, etc. as well as some basic usage under a few different programming languages (Python, Lua, etc.)